# Uploading data to server using JSON

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload multiple images to the server (PHP back end) from android phone , what I'm trying to do is that i want my function to call it self when it returns success on response but with different data , so i want to move to the next object in my array list if the first object was uploaded successfully . I'm currently calling the function using for loop which is uploading multiple images at the same time which will consume a lot of connection on 3g so i prefer to upload them one by one and retry in case i lost connection or failed to upload .
please any one who would help me i would be thankful

that is my code

```
private void uploaddata() {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("uploading to server ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_Uploadfirstparty, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    String accidentid="";
                    if(acc.getAccid()==null)
                    {
                         accidentid = jObj.getString("recordid");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "accident"+accidentid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         accidentid = acc.getAccid();
                    }



                    String thid="0";
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                        if(acc.p[i]!=null)
                        {
                            uploadimages(imgstring(acc.p[i].getPhoto()),acc.p[i].getPosition(),Integer.parseInt(accidentid),acc.p[i].getComment(),thid);

                        }
                    }



                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("carid", Integer.toString(acc.getCarid()));
            params.put("expertid",Integer.toString(acc.getExpertid()));
            params.put("longtitude",Double.toString(acc.getLongtitude()));
            params.put("latitude",Double.toString(acc.getLatitude()));
            params.put("injuries",Integer.toString(acc.getInjuries()));
            params.put("location",acc.getLocation());
            params.put("time",acc.getTime());
            params.put("accid",acc.getAccid());
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
}


private void uploadimage(final String image,final String thid,final int pos,final int id) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("uploading images to server ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_Uploadfirstpartyphoto, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    String noerror = jObj.getString("noerror");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            noerror, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("image",image);
            params.put("pos",Integer.toString(pos));
            params.put("thid",thid);
            params.put("accidentid",Integer.toString(id));

            return params;
        }

    };
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

Comment: What is the question? help you with what? how far have you gotten and what have you tried?

Comment: i need a way so that the function upload image can call it self each time with new data instead of using for loop ! so that i can detect if one of the images failed to upload

Comment: use AsyncTask to upload 1 pic at a time and return success if it was successfully uploaded then call it in a for loop if (response == sucess) go to the other and upload it through the same AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using recursion !

```
private void uploadimages2(final int i,final int j) {

    if(i>j)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        if(acc.p[i]!=null)
        {


        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("uploading images to server ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_Uploadfirstpartyphotoacc, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        uploadimages2((i+1),j);

                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("image",imgstring(acc.p[i].getPhoto()));
                params.put("pos",Integer.toString(acc.p[i].getPosition()));
                params.put("accidentid",acc.getAccid());
                params.put("cmnt",acc.p[i].getComment());
                params.put("thid","0");

                return params;
            }

        };
        strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
        else
        {
            uploadimages2(i+1,j);
        }
    }


}
```